# Invalid or unexpected token "��" when trying to test with mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I'm trying to get into unit testing, but when I try to test my code I'm getting this in the terminal:

```
 D:\VS Code\VS Code\tests\test\test.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ��'
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at C:\Users\SSD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:230:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (C:\Users\SSD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:227:14)
    at Mocha.run (C:\Users\SSD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:495:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\SSD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha:469:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
```

I followed the steps given in the mocha documentation here:
 https://mochajs.org/#installation

1. npm install mocha
2. mkdir test
3. $null > test/test.js

Then I literally copied and pasted the example

```
    var assert = require('assert');
describe('Array', function() {
  describe('#indexOf()', function() {
    it('should return -1 when the value is not present', function() {
      assert.equal(-1, [1,2,3].indexOf(4));
    });
  });
});
```

Set up the test in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
"test": "mocha"
```

}

Then ran the command `npm test`
No matter what test example I take the error is the same. I've also tried to uninstall and install mocha again, I've tried chai also. Same error.

Comment: I had this problem with VSCode as well.  I think the file encoding got messed up somehow.  I ended up copying the text content into a new file, and it was fine after that.

Answer (score 1):

I have just delete de file math.js, copy his content and created new file if same name and paste the same program again, and it works.

example:

```
const assert = require('assert');
const Math = require('../scr/math.js');


describe('Math class', function() {
    it('Sum two numbers', function() {
        const math = new Math();
        assert.equal(math.sum(5, 5), 10);
    });
});

file math.js: 

class Math {
    sum = function sum(a,b) { };
}

module.exports = Math;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Actually I tried creating the test js file using the windows cmd instead of touch cmd from git bash, then I pasted the code as it was mentioned in this tutorial https://buddy.works/guides/how-automate-nodejs-unit-tests-with-mocha-chai.

Just delete the test.js file and create using touch cmd. It should work fine after that.